# How can I safely exchange Bitcoins for Ethers?

Tags: bitcoin, exchanges

I would like to sell Bitcoins and buy Ethers. I know there are some exchange websites, but I cannot tell which are trustworthy. What are safest and easiest ways to sell Bitcoins and buy Ethers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use poloniex or coinbase to buy ethers using your bitcoins, they are trustworty and efficient (with a high liquidity volume)

Answer (score 0):

To exchange Bitcoin for [Ethereum](https://koinbx.com/trade/ETH-INR), follow some simple steps:

• Sign up with a global crypto exchange platform such as [KoinBX](https://koinbx.com/) and create an account.
• Complete the KYC verification and bank account verification.
• Once the account is created and verified, you can deposit funds into your wallet.
• Select the ETH pair that you want to exchange.

To sell Bitcoin, the user needs to place a sell order for Bitcoin. Once the order was matched with a buyer holding Ethereum and wishing to exchange Bitcoin for Ethereum, Bitcoin will be exchanged for Ethereum and deposited in your KoinBX wallet.